# Iteration throw model property in scaffolding template

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to create a controller template. In this template, I need to iterate throw the properties in the model. In this article http://matt-ward.blogspot.com/2011/10/asp-net-mvc-3-t4-template-properties.html I found the variable that can be used in the template but it seems that there is not a variable that can help. Is there any suggestion?